# Perl check if file exists in url to be fetched

Tags: perl, download

whilst performing file::fetch on a database of URLs, certain URLs contain only the top level domain such as http://google.com.  How can i construct my if check such that it will verify that there is a file to fetched so when i create a new file::fetch object, it wouldnt throw me this error:

`Use of uninitialized value $path in pattern match (m//) at C:/Perl/lib/File/Spec/Unix.pm line 267.

Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:/Perl/lib/File/Fetch.pm line 395.`

Here is a snippet of my code where i am trying to do some verification

```
my $uri_handle = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
my $getfile = $uri_handle ->file;
if ($getfile){
    my $dir_handle = $uri_handle->fetch( to => $dir ) or die "Couldn't fetch file: $uri_handle->error\n";
    #print "[ID:$myid] File fetch completed!\n\n";
}else{
    print "[ID:$myid] There is no file to be fetched from $url\n\n";
}
```

But the file method fails too because it could not retrieve a file name at the URL.

```
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Can't call method "file" on an undefined value at C:\test\multihashtest2.pl line 102.
```

Comment: Is there a function or a module to help me verify that there is the URL points to a file to be fetched. Supposedly i can use such a function to do validation checks before i create the object such that file::fetch wouldnt fail

Comment: It would be nice to see some code, not just the error.  The new method is supposed to return false on failure.  Anyway, you could use Try::Tiny or wrap it in an eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your perl script will not know what is on the webserver and what isn't until it tries to load a URI -- it doesn't matter what the URL looks like. You'll need to attempt to fetch the file and gracefully handle any errors.

It would help if you posted your code, but you can probably answer your own question by looking at [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Fetch.html).

In particular, the `new()` method `returns false on error`, but that's just validating the URI before it's actually fetched. When you call `fetch()` on your File::Fetch object, it `Returns the full path to the downloaded file on success, and false on failure.`

So handle what those methods return accordingly.

**EDIT:** now that you posted code. If the error is complaining that $uri_handle is undefined, check that $url is being set properly and check for errors. After line 1:

```
print $url;
print $uri_handle->error;
```

Comment: the URL is indeed defined but File::Fetch object will remain undefined `Thread 2 terminated abnormally: Can't call method "error" on an undefined value at C:\test\multihashtest2.pl line 104.`
because i think my URLs happen to not have files to be fetched. (my situation happens that some have files to be fetched and some dont)  
I think the best way then is to try what @Bill had said and use try::tiny

Comment: by the way, line 104 is the `my $uri_handle = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);`

Comment: I would take a look at Unix.pm and Fetch.pm in the lines given in the error. It's possible that since a pattern match is failing, it's expecting a period in the last part of the path, or a `.html` etc., which would confirm your suspicion. When you request just a remote directory, it's up to the webserver to decide what file to actually serve up -- usually it's a list consisting of `index.html,index.htm,index.php`, etc